# Query a specific JSON column (postgres) with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a model with a JSON field:

```
class Item(db.Model)
   ...
   data = db.Column(JSON, nullable=False)
   ...
```

The data contains some JSON such as:

```
{
    "cost": 10.00,
    "passengers": 2,
    "surcharge": 1.6
}
```

I want to be able to get a sum of the cost across all rows in the table with a filter. I tried the following but that didn't seem to work.

```
db.session.query(func.count(Item.data['cost'])).filter(
          Item.data["surcharge"].cast(Float) > 1
      ).scalar()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the wrong [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). `count(expression)` counts the number of rows for which the *expression* is not null. If you want a sum, use `sum(expression)`:

```
db.session.query(func.sum(Item.data['cost'].astext.cast(Numeric))).\
    filter(Item.data['surcharge'].astext.cast(Numeric) > 1).\
    scalar()
```

Note that monetary values and binary floating point math is a bad mixture due to [binary floats not being able to represent all decimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Instead use a proper [monetary type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html), or [`Numeric`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric) in which case SQLAlchemy uses [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) to represent the results in Python.

Comment: Though PostgreSQL `JSONB` stores numbers in numeric, and `JSON` as decimal strings... However, needs some special handling with Python ...

Comment: Great answer but I had to use `as_string()` instead of `astext` (SQLAlchemy 1.3.23)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Float`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Float) instead of [`Integer`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Integer) as argument of [`cast`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=cast#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast)

```
db.session.query(func.count(Item)).filter(
          Item.data['surcharge'].cast(Float) > 1
      ).all()
```

Comment: Fair point, I've updated the query but that still doesn't work. It just returns 0.