# Explicitly cast from JSON to double precision in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am implementing a query for average, but how can I explicitly define double in SQLAlchemy as defined in the below PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT avg((tags->>'price')::double precision) from parcel_table
```

The Python:

```
parcel_table.query.\
    with_entities(
        func.avg(parcel_table.tags["price"]).
            label('average`')).\
    filter(
        parcel_table.time_stamp.between("'2017-01-01 00:00:000'",
                                        "'2017-10-01 00:00:000'"),
        parcel_table.name== 'sakshi').\
    first()
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
(tags->>'price')::double precision
```

being a [JSON index operation with a cast](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON) has a nice shortcut in SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

parcel_table.tags["price"].astext.cast(postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION)
```

Note that the name "price" would hint at this being about money, and [floating point numbers and money are a bad match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45691529/2681632), usually.

Comment: with_entities is not working in python as query is coming correct but due to with_entities data is not coming in python can you help me for that,

Comment: I think problem is not with with_entities

Comment: problem is due to astext.cast(postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION)
if I am averaging other number without DOUBLE_PRECISION then it is working fine

Comment: I'm afraid you've lost me. Do you get some error, or just invalid results? What did you do, and what did you expect as results?

Comment: To add to the previous, `Model.json['foo'].astext.cast(<numeric type>)` should be and is fine, if all values under *foo* are either numbers, strings representing numbers, or JSON nulls. If you have some other data, the cast will fail.

Comment: I am getting output none

Comment: is this problem due to null

Comment: That'd sound like all your values are NULL. Are you sure you're using the correct key? The indexing operator will return NULL if accessing a non existent key, as noted [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). Of course `AVG()` will result in NULL if your query results in 0 rows as well, so also check your filter predicates.